# tensorflow dataset from_generator() out of range error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` to generate training and validation data.

I have my own data generator which does feature preparation on the fly:

```
def data_iterator(self, input_file_list, ...):
    for f in input_file_list:
        X, y = get_feature(f)
        yield X, y
```

Initially I was feeding this directly to tensorflow keras model but I encounter data out of range error after the first batch. Then I decided to wrap this within tensorflow data generator:

```
train_gen = lambda: data_iterator(train_files, ...)
valid_gen = lambda: data_iterator(valid_files, ...)

output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32)
output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape([499, 13]), tf.TensorShape([2]))
train_dat = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(train_gen,
                                           output_types=output_types,
                                           output_shapes=output_shapes)
valid_dat = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(valid_gen,
                                           output_types=output_types,
                                           output_shapes=output_shapes)
train_dat = train_dat.repeat().batch(batch_size=128)
valid_dat = valid_dat.repeat().batch(batch_size=128)
```

Then fit:

```
model.fit(x=train_dat,
          validation_data=valid_dat,
          steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
          validation_steps=valid_steps,
          epochs=100,
          callbacks=callbacks)
```

However, I'm still getting the error despite having `.repeat()` in the generator:

> BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence

My question is:

- why is `.repeat()` not working here?
- should I add a `while True` in my own iterator to avoid this? I feel like this can fix it but it doesn't look like the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @thushv89 Unfortunately I don't have mine anymore as I started with another test run and overwritten the log. But it's the same as in here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31509 or probably any post that reported this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a while True in my own generator so that it never run out and I'm not getting error any more:

```
def data_iterator(self, input_file_list, ...):
    while True;
        for f in input_file_list:
            X, y = get_feature(f)
            yield X, y
```

However, I don't know why `.repeat()` is not working for `.from_generator()`